# How can merge data using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to merge data with my query.right now with my query I get data like this below I have show my o/p.

And in the query NotificationTextId = 1 is for follow type case.

This is my query =>

```
SELECT
    N.NotificationId,
    N.UserId,
    N.ActionUserId,
    AU.ProfileImage,
    (CASE
       WHEN N.NotificationTypeId = 1
          THEN
             (SELECT REPLACE(NT.NotificationText), '##UserName##', (SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE UserId = N.ActionUserId))
              FROM NotificationTexts NT
              WHERE NT.NotificationTextId = 1)
       WHEN N.NotificationTypeId = 2
          THEN
            (SELECT REPLACE(NT.NotificationText), '##UserName##', (SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE UserId = N.ActionUserId))
             FROM NotificationTexts NT
             WHERE NT.NotificationTextId = 2)
    END) AS NotificationText,
    AU.UserName,
    N.NotificationTypeId,
    N.InsertDateTime
FROM
    Notification N
INNER JOIN
    Users U ON N.UserId = U.UserId
INNER JOIN
    Users AU ON N.ActionUserId = AU.UserId
ORDER BY
    N.InsertDateTime DESC
```

This is my current output:

```
NotificationId | UserId | ActionUserId | UserName | NotificationTypeId | InsertDateTime            | ProfileImage             | NotificationText
 7                21        18             h        2                    2017-06-22 17:14:16.803    20170416032403810.jpeg       h like you.
 6                20        15             a        1                    2017-06-22 17:14:16.803    20170416032403869.jpeg       a started follow you.
 5                20        16             b        1                    2017-06-22 17:12:12.297     20170416031522534.jpeg      b started follow you.
 4                20        17             c        1                    2017-06-22 17:11:58.060     20170416031250102.jpeg      c started follow you.
 3                10        11             d        1                    2017-06-22 16:14:16.803     20170416032403867.jpeg      d started follow you.
 2                10        12             e        1                    2017-06-22 16:14:12.297     20170416031522533.jpeg      e started follow you.
 1                10        13             f        1                    2017-06-22 16:13:58.060     20170416031250101.jpeg      f started follow you.
```

This is my excepted output:

```
  NotificationId | UserId | ActionUserId | UserName | NotificationTypeId | InsertDateTime            | ProfileImage           | NotificationText
  7                21        18             h        2                    2017-06-22 17:14:16.803    20170416032403810.jpeg    h like you.
  6                20        15             a        1                    2017-06-22 17:14:16.803    20170416032403869.jpeg    a,b and 1  other users followed you
  3                10        11             d        1                    2017-06-22 16:14:16.803    20170416032403867.jpeg    d,e and 1  other users followed you
```

I have created a query with try using with clause but this query how can impalement with my query.

```
WITH d AS
(
    SELECT  
        n.NotificationID, n.UserID,
        n.ActionUserID, au.UserName,
        n.NotificationTypeID, au.ProfileImage,
        (SELECT CaseType FROM Cases WHERE CaseId = N.CaseId) AS CaseType,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY n.UserID ORDER BY n.InsertDateTime DESC) AS rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY n.UserID) AS c,
        N.InsertDateTime
    FROM 
        dbo.Notifications N
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Users U ON N.UserId = U.UserId
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Users AU ON N.ActionUserId = AU.UserId
    WHERE
        N.UserId = 20
        AND N.NotificationTypeID  = 1
)
SELECT
    d.NotificationID, d.ActionUserID,
    d.CaseId,
    d.UserName
      + ISNULL(CASE WHEN d2.c = 2
                       THEN ' and '
                       ELSE ', '
               END + d2.UserName, '')
      + CASE 
           WHEN d2.c > 2
              THEN ' and ' + CAST(d2.c - 2 AS NVARCHAR(10)) + ' other users'
              ELSE ''
        END
      + ' followed you.' AS NotificationText,
    d.ProfileImage, d.UserName, d.NotificationTypeID
FROM 
    d
LEFT JOIN 
    d AS d2 ON (d.UserID = d2.UserID AND d2.rn = 2)
WHERE 
    d.rn = 1 
ORDER BY 
    d.InsertDateTime DESC;
```

With this query I am successful for merging my data but just only notificationtypeid = 1. I want to data also for id 2. how can merge this query in my sp or any onther way then please also tell me.

Comment: You can go with union using your query and 'with' clause query. may be it's use full for you.